# Spliting a double/int into 2 different values

Tags: java

Im a bit new to programming and im stuck with a few questions I have to do.

In the questions I have to create a program which turns change (money) into "pounds:" and "pence:". How would I do this with a single double such as 154p = Pound: 1 Pence: 54.

I also have to do the same with converting feet & Inches into Meters: and Cm:. i.e. 5 foot 11 inches = 1m 80cm.

I believe there is a simple way of doing this, I just cant figure it out.

This is what I have so far for feet and inches program.

```
package measure;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Measure {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter Feet: ");
      int feet = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Inches: ");
      int inches = input.nextInt();
    double result = ((feet * 12) + inches);
    double cm = result*2.54;

    System.out.println((int)cm);
```

As you can see, I can get the full cm's but not the convert it to Meter and Cm.

Comment: Learn about [the arithmetic operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html), especially about the _division operator_ `/` and the _remainder operator_ `%` (also called modulo operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to convert the cm you obtained to m. You need to us the division operator `/` and the remainder operator `%`

As an example:

```
 38 = 9 x 4 + 2
 38 / 9 = 4 and 38 % 9 = 2
```

For more information about these, take a look at this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Therefore, adding this code to the end will do the work:

```
int meter = (int)cm / 100;
int remainingCM = (int)(cm-meter*100);
System.out.println((int)meter + "m and " + remainingCM + " cm!" );
```

Comment: Ah, totally forgot about the %. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Just made an edit on the line beginning with "int remainingCM...". Take a look at that!